# Django: Syntax error in urls.py line 10

Tags: python, django

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from testesonline import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^fat_controller$', views.fat_controller, name='index_no_model',
    url(r'^with_model$', views.model_controller, name='model_controller',
    url(r'^MVC$', views.MVC_way, name='MVC_way'),
)
```

What is missing in here to give me error?

Answer (score 1):

You have two lines which are missing close parentheses.

Comment: HINT: Start by looking at `line 10`, and traverse backward from there. Repeat when you get another error.